# Transfer xml data to Oracle table by column or fields by using talend

Tags: oracle, talend, data-integration

I am using Talend Studio with objects tFileInputDelimited row1(Main) to tOracleOutput what I want is to transfer the data in xml file to Oracle table.
I want to transfer the values of the last two columns (product_label and email_order) of my excel file to the product table which has this column structure (PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_CODE,PRODUCT_LABEL,EMAIL_COMAND
ORDER_ID).
Also, I want to process this condition if a row in my excel file contains an empty product code column then is not insert the column values product_label and email_command.

[XML File to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNG7S.png)

[Product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzLcM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8qBA.png)

what is the proper settings in tFileInputDelimited , or do I need to use other tools?

Comment: This is not clear. tFileInputDelimited is not suited to work with XML files. Try tFileInputXML. Your first link "XML File to Load" does NOT show a XML file. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

[Refer this image for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShMR9.png)

Use tFileInputXMl file and filter the records by using tFilterRow and then connect with tOracleOutput